# How to round to certain numbers

Tags: c#

I have some Input (double values) for example 4329 and I have to round it to certain numbers:

4200, 5200, 6200, 7200... 25200

I want it to always round up so 4329 will become 5200.

Currently I do it with 21 ifs but that does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: You logic of *Round to certain number* will all depend on your business logic, if number should round up to high or low number. Can you please post the exact business rules require for calculation and your code to achieve it so that other users can respond to it?

Comment: It always should round up 1 to 4200, 4400 to 5200, 8201 to 9200, 12000 to 12200 etc...

Comment: What happens if the input is 25201?

Comment: I coded a Limit with a Pop up window.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by double input?

Comment: I ment Floating Point values.

Comment: @BrettCaswell `double` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a combination of `Math.Ceiling` and `Math.Max` you can do it by subtracting the starting number, dividing the interval, then taking the ceiling, then max with `0.0`, then undoing the dividing and offset:

```
double firstThreshold = 4200;
double interval = 1000;

double output = Math.Max(
        0.0, 
        Math.Ceiling( (input - firstThreshold) / interval )
        ) * interval + firstThreshold;
```

It's a little unclear what should happen if the input is greater than 25200, so if that's a hard maximum, you can use `Math.Min` to set the max to 25200 if you need that:

```
double firstThreshold = 4200;
double interval = 1000;
double maxValue = 25200;

double output = Math.Min(maxValue,
        Math.Max(
            0.0, 
            Math.Ceiling( (input - firstThreshold ) / interval )
            ) * interval + firstThreshold);
```

These don't require traversing or populating a list and so are constant time.

Comment: Works best for me thank you. Actually my bad i Need Floating Point because the value is in meter and i will calculate it into mm but yea i didn't mention that my bad.

Comment: @tenminmail double is a floating point type and you did say you had double input...

Comment: Actually i did mention it don't know what selbie means.

Comment: well.. his comment was in regards to this solution, which does floating-point arithmetic as an alternative the solutions that don't.  I tend to think the same here.  You think the 21 if statement checks were not 'good' - but that is subjective actually.  A short-circuited predicate check on integer values can be considerable better then division and multiplication operations on double-point values.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer, and it's a solid one.. but it's probably going to be a scenario where the answer doesn't reflect the most agreeable answer (assuming people who up and down vote consider as much)

Comment: @BrettCaswell I am trying to avoid assuming that asker's interval or starting value is always an integer. They never say it will always need to round to a whole number or integer, that's only the case in the specific case in the question.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
using System.Linq;
(...)

var limits = new []{4200, 4400,5200,8201,9200,12000,12200};

var number = 300;

var ceiled = limits.First(l => l >= number);
```

Comment: You could have a *dynamic* list of values, to avoid the hard-coded one. Something like: `int lowValue = 4200;` `int highValue = 25200;` `int increment = 1000;` 
`var limits = Enumerable.Range(1, (highValue - lowValue) / increment).Select(n => lowValue + (n * increment)).ToList();`. So one can input the values that determine the intervals at any time (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like recommend this method with clue of your question title [round]

not as [round up]

if it's [round up], tymtam's answer will be fit for that.

**Import Area**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Math;
```

**Code Area**

```
// Target List Which you will get as a result
List<int> Targets = new List<int>();
Targets.AddRange(new int[] { 4200, 5200, 6200, 7200, 9200, 11200, 11700, 15300, 17200, 20000, 23000, 25200 });

// Target value which you will check
int InputNo = 4329;

// Region for Round
{
    // This print 4200 for 4329
    // and 15300 for 15400

    // Check differences between Targets' elements and InputNo
    List<int> Diffs = Targets.Select(x => Math.Abs(x - InputNo)).ToList();
    int index = Diffs.IndexOf(Diffs.Min());

    // Print Result
    Console.WriteLine("Round Result => " + Targets[index]);
}

// Region for Round Up
{
    int Result = -1;

    try
    {
        Result = Targets.Where(x => (x >= InputNo)).First();
    }
    catch
    {
        Result = Targets.Max();
    }

    // This prints Round up values.
    // if InputNo is bigger than any Elements, it'll be return Max values of elements
    Console.WriteLine("Round Up Result => " + Result);
}
```

Comment: 15300 for 15400 -> this is wrong for me since from 15300 i want 16200

Comment: @tenminmail : this is for round. not for round up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this often, you could create yourself an *extension method*

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static int RoundTo(this int source, params int[] values) 
      => values.OrderBy(x => x).First(x => x >= source);
}
```

**Usage 1**

```
var input = 4329;
var result = input.RoundTo(4200, 5200, 6200, 7200, 25200);
```

**Usage 2**

```
var array = new[] { 4200, 5200, 6200, 7200, 25200 };
var input = 4329;
var result = input.RoundTo(array);
```

**Output**

```
5200
5200
```

If you need to support more than *int*, add pepper and salt to taste

```
public static int RoundTo(this double source, params int[] values)
   => values.OrderBy(x => x).First(x => x >= source);

public static int RoundTo(this decimal source, params int[] values)
   => values.OrderBy(x => x).First(x => x >= source);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Func<double, double> roundingFunc = (double x) => Math.Ceiling((x - 200) / 1000) * 1000 + 200;
```